# TextBoxWatermarkExtender property equivalent to CssClass

Tags: css, asp.net

Below is my code which I thought would work

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
<style type="text/css">
                .watermark{
                    color: Gray;
                    background-color: #dddddd;
                    font-size: smaller;
                    font-style: italic;
                }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>

            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

            <asp:TextBox ID="txtInput" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            ontextchanged="txtInput_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>


            <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txtInput_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" 
                runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtInput"  CssClass="watermark"
                WatermarkText="Some text">
            </cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
```

But I get error `Type 'AjaxControlToolkit.TextBoxWatermarkExtender' does not have a public property named 'CssClass'.`

What is a class does TextBoxWatermarkExtender have that is equivalent to CssClass? Or is there another way to make this work?

How to fix?

Comment: The error message itself is pretty clear.

Comment: So many downvotes .... are we trying to get winter hats???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, [TextBoxWatermarkExtender WatermarkCssClass overwrites TextBox CssClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755995/textboxwatermarkextender-watermarkcssclass-overwrites-textbox-cssclass)

An equivalent class to `CssClass` is `WatermarkCssClass`

Corrected code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
<style type="text/css">
                .watermark{
                    color: Gray;
                    background-color: #dddddd;
                    font-size: smaller;
                    font-style: italic;
                }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>

            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

            <asp:TextBox ID="txtInput" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            ontextchanged="txtInput_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>


            <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txtInput_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" 
                runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtInput"  WatermarkCssClass="watermark"
                WatermarkText="Some text">
            </cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
```

When I press F5, here is output

[image]